# Is it possible to block capabilities in a USB device?

Tags: linux, usb, hid

I have a USB device which communicates with a wireless handheld remote (Dupad G20S Pro Plus). It works great on my debian box. The problem I am trying to solve is preventing the power button on the remote from shutting down the system (I guess the remote is more intended for smart TVs).

I did at least figure out via lsusb the offending device capability is:

```
% lsusb -vd 4842:0001
...
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               2.01
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     121
          Report Descriptor: (length is 121)
...
            Item(Local ): Usage, data= [ 0x81 ] 129
                            System Power Down
...
```

Is there a way to block this capability at some kernel level? I did find I can block shutdowns in general with systemd-inhibit, but would love to use something lower level (like udev).

**Update**:

This is for a debian server (not desktop). The key events are being captured for home automation purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue to the solution (for a systemd based linux host) comes from [man logind.conf(8)](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd/logind.conf.5.en.html).

> Only input devices with the "power-switch" udev tag will be watched for key/lid switch events.

Indeed this tag is added by the [default udev rules](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/login/70-power-switch.rules):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="event*", ENV{ID_INPUT_KEY}=="1", TAG+="power-switch"
```

I was able to block the action by commenting the rules out in that file (/etc/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules).

**Additional Info:**

My original fix attempt was to remove the tag with this new rule in a new file `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-power-switch.rules` (processed after `70-power-switch.rules`):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="event*", TAG-="power-switch"
```

Even though my version of systemd supported tag removal (249), I could not get it to work. My best guess is systemd has already been alerted to the original tag, and removing the tag is not supported.

Comment: Interesting, my ancient Devuan system doesn't even have `70-power-switch.rules`...

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I am trying to solve is preventing the power button on the remote from shutting down the system

First thing to do is to find out **how** this works in Linux, and what part of your Linux system listens to the "power button" event (I am actually surprised one part does). And the descriptor may or may not be involved into that.

First thing I'd try is to identify the input device (look at the symlinks in `/dev/input/by-*`, they map to a concrete `/dev/input/eventX`. You can use `evtest` to see which one of those produces the other keypresses. Then do a `evtest --grab` on it, and if the power button stops working, it's processed by some later stage (e.g. your Desktop environment, so look at which one you use, and if you can configure it). If it still works, it's in an earlier stage (kernel module, so you need to start looking at the kernel).

Comment: Yeah turns out its systemd that implements the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If the power button on the remote only shuts down the system when you're logged in, then it's probably handled by your desktop environment.

Debian's default desktop environment is GNOME, and it handles things like these via the `gsd-media-keys` plugin of the GNOME Settings Daemon. I'm more of a KDE guy myself, so I don't have a system with GNOME at hand I could use to test this. But with a bit of Googling, I found only that the old ways to configure things like this no longer work in modern versions of GNOME :-(

---

If the remote's power button also causes a shutdown when nobody is logged in, then it's probably handled by `logind`. In that case, the solution may be simple.

In `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, there is a number of commented-out lines for determining how to handle certain special keys and switches.

By default, all these lines are commented out and `logind` makes the keys and switches do what they're generally supposed to do, e.g. a "power" key on the keyboard will trigger a controlled shutdown. And since your remote control's power button probably pretends to be a "power" key on a USB keyboard, that's exactly the function you'll want to disable!

You'll find a commented-out line in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` like this:

```
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
```

You'll want to edit the file to uncomment the line, and change it to:

```
HandlePowerKey=ignore
```

To be honest, I'm not sure if changes to `logind`'s configuration will take effect immediately, or only after a reboot. The man pages don't seem to mention this fact either way, and there does not seem to be a documented way to signal `logind` that it should reload its configuration.

Comment: Even though I posted my own solution after many more hours of research, I think this is the best solution. Don't have the rep to vote yet though :(.

Comment: You can still click on the green checkmark to mark a solution as the accepted one - doing that is actually worth a vote and a half by itself. You probably should wait a few days before doing that, in case other answers will get posted.